# Please help with my twodimensional array source code

Tags: java

Here is what i have done but i have some questions:

```
class masivins {
    public static void main (String args[]) {

        int mas[][] = {{0, 2, 7, 0, 8, 5, 3},
                       {0, 4, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0},
                       {0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0},
                       {7, 0, 0, 9, 1, 0, 7},
                       {5, 0, 4, 0, 0, 2, 0}};

        int nulmas[] =  new int [7]; 
        int nul=0; 

        for(int j=0; j<7; j++) {
            nul=0;
            for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
                if(mas[i][j]==0) { 
                    nul++;          
                }
            }
            nulmas[j]=nul; 
        }
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<7; j++) {
                System.out.println(mas[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();

        for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {

            System.out.println("Zeros in each array column: " + nulmas[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

so my questions are:

1. Why after running project there are only 5 "Zeros in each array column....." shown?
2. What and where i need to change in this code to get out the number of column in which zeros are least?

Comment: i wish i could be back in school some days

Comment: So what's the question here ? What precisely are you having difficulty with ?

Comment: i need to get out index of column in which zeros are least < this is my problem, i cant do this :(

Comment: +1 OP has made an attempt to do the homework.

Comment: Previous similar question from OP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484752/please-help-with-my-twodimensional-array-source-code

Comment: @Baiba: Please change the title of your question. it's almost useless: this site is about programming, you tagged the question as Java, it says nothing about your question. (missing 103 rep to edit it myself...)

Comment: @Lirik looks like the OP took the previous stuff from the previous question and now is confused again. With the rest of the code already gathered from stackoverflow, the addition of searching for the lowest zero is stupidly easy. I'd tag this 'do-my-homework-for-me' but 'homework' suffices.

Comment: @Chris I wish I could go out and cross out all the statements you've corrected me on :).

Comment: @Lirik lol, I only just noticed you were the one I corrected on the == true thing. You haven't made that many mistakes, plus the code worked anyway :) I used to do that *all* the time. I just noticed on his posting history that he was giving the community stuff to do in piecemeal fashion to mask his activity ;)

Answer (score 2):

Question 1 - look at your code:

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
    System.out.println("Zeros in each array column: " + nulmas[i]);
}
```

In particular, look at the loop. How many lines do you *expect* it to print out?

Question 2: You could keep a "least number of 0s in an array column so far" and "column in which the least number of 0s appeared" - then update those variables at the end of the inner loop where you set `nulmas[j]`.

Comment: Ok, but when i change the code to for(int i=0; i<7; i++) 
             for(int j=0; j<5; j++);
after project running it says me "Exception in thread "main"                      java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
    at masivins.main(masivins.java:19)

Comment: then update those variables at the end of the inner loop where you set nulmas[j] < how can i do that??

Comment: @Baiba: First point: why would you want two loops? And what's the body of your loop? Second point: you test whether you need to update them (whether `nul` is less than your current "least number of 0s") and if so, you update the "least number of 0s" variable to `nul` and the new "column with least number of 0s" to `i`.

Comment: actually, i don't know why there are two loops, i made this program from examples and i don't understand why it is like that!!!

Comment: @Baiba check the code example in my answer, hope it helps :-)

Comment: ok i have another version of this code, please tell me what i need to do when i need to get out of program The INDEX NUMBER OF COLUMN IN WHICH ARE LEAST ZEROS?

Comment: @Baiba: I've already explained to you how to do it. Presumably this is a homework question - I've given you all the hints you should need; I'm not just going to write out the code for you.

Answer (score 1):

1) because you loop from 0 to 4:

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
```

If you looped until 7, all values would be printed out:

```
for(int i=0; i<7; i++) {
    System.out.println("Zeros in each array column: " + nulmas[i]);
}
```

2) you could keep an index and a minimum counter. The min counter stores the minimum number of zeros, the index the column where this is found:

```
int nulmas[] =  new int [7]; 
int nul=0; 
int minNuls=5;
int minIndex=0;

for(int j=0; j<7; j++) {
    nul=0;
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        if(mas[i][j]==0) { 
            nul++;          
        }
    }
    nulmas[j]=nul; 
    if (nul < minNul) {
        minNul = nul;
        minIndex = j;
    }
}
```

Comment: for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {

            System.out.println("Zeros in each array column: " + nulmas[i]);
what i need to change in this place?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be very close to answering the question. It looks to me like you've set up the `nul_mas` array to contain the number of zeros in each column, so the question becomes "which index of `nul_mas` has the smallest value?". You can do this with two variables - one for the smallest value seen so far, one for the index where it was seen - and a loop through that array to look at each element in turn. (Then, when you've got it working, consider what happens if there is a tie.)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
 int leastZeroIndex = 0;

 for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
   if (nul_mas[i] < nul_mas[leastZeroIndex])
     leastZeroIndex = i;
 }

 System.out.print(leastZeroIndex);
```

Though there is no check if there are multiple rows with the lowest amount of zeros.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as if you need to create some new arrays, so create an array for each column, and then put the numbers for the column in there. After that, just iterate over that array of arrays which represent the columns and count the numbers (you could use a method for doing this, i.e., `int count(int num, int[] arr)`. I think this'll give the least amount of code.

```
int[][] mas  = ...; // (you have this already), it's [NO_OF_ARRS][NO_OF_COLS] with the data
int[][] colsarrs = new int[NO_OF_COLS][NO_OF_ARRS];

for (int i = 0; i < NO_OF_ARRS; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < NO_OF_COLS; i++) {
        colsarrs[j][i] = mas[i][j];
    }
}

int[] resultarr = new int[NO_OF_COLS];
for (int i = 0; i < NO_OF_COLS; i++) {
    resultarr[i] = count(0, colsarrs[i]);
}

int count(int num, int[] arr) {
    int count;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == num) ++count;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Store the amount of zeros in an additional array (resultarr) gathered from this function for each column. After this, go over the array and find the lowest number, and grab the index of it. That's your column with the lowest amount of zeroes.

```
int lowestcurr = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < NO_OF_COLS; i++) {
    if (resultarr[i] < resultarr[lowestcurr]) {
        lowestcurr = i;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please write how it looks when it is in source code because i dont understand

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>     for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
>
>         System.out.println("Zeros in each array column: " + nulmas[i]);
>     }
>     System.out.println(); place there it
> ```

change it on :

```
int minElement = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<7; i++) {
        if (nulmas[i] < nulmas[minElement]) minElement = i;
        System.out.println("Zeros in each array column: " + nulmas[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(nulmas[minElement]);
```

better use "\n" to skip one line in console